# Get the distance moved by finger during touchmove Event Jquery

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari, ipad-2, touch-event

I have a Jquery carousal which I have coded to move on the touchmove event. On testing on iPad 2, Safari browser it is working. Now I want to do 2 things:

- Get the direction in which the finger moved so the carousal moves accordingly(Right to left or Left to Right).
- Get the intensity(or distance) of touchmove so that the carousal moves in such a speed.

For this I was trying to get the X coordinate of the start point and the end point of the touchmove event, but `event.pageX` returns only 1 value. I have tried getting the values from `'touchstart'` and `'touchend'` event also, but that also does not work. I have even tried getting  the `event.originalEvent.touches.length` and `event.originalEvent.changedTouches.length` but its always returned as 1.

Am I approaching this in the right way? How can I get the 2 values of pageX? And if there is a more optimum way of achieving the 2 points above, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well. event.originalEvent.touches and event.originalEvent.changedTouches is arrays of touches. 1 means you are just touching with one finger...

Comment: see this page http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of using touchmove, I added the Jquery mobile library(http://jquerymobile.com/). It has a swipe event, as well as Swipe Left and Swipe Right event. This gives me the direction of the swipe. Still have not figured out the intensity part though.